# Is there any way to send stream of local RTSP of IP camera and access it from android application?

Tags: android, rtsp, ip-camera

I want to create application on STB device which will send stream of ip camera to some server and from their i can access the stream on multiple android mobile devices.

I have local RTSP link of ip camera stream but not able to figure out how and where to send the stream so that i can access it outside the network.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this url that you have is for streaming, maybe you can try to display it with https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer?

Comment: ExoPlayer is to play the stream right ?
I am able to play rtsp stream locally thats not the issue but i want to send stream to cloud.
I mean i want to use ip camera as default camera for stb